# Two Jqgrids focus and data submit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm been trying in a page with two JqGrids (Both grids are using editing in cells) get this feature.

Here is the problem with an example:
-If you are in the Grid1 and edit a cell and then click another cell in Grid1 JqGrid send the input.
-If you are in the Grid1 and edit a cell and then you click in a cell of the Grid2, JqGrid don't send the content, the cell of the Grid1 keep in the input "style" for editing.

I was trying to acomplish this in:
 - the editoptions > dataInit event
 - with a j('#Grid1).live("click", function(){ });

There, I save the value of the elem input, and then try to simulate the enter event, so the JqGrid can send the data to the server, in both cases with no sucess.

Ideas?

Comment: you could use the document.onclick() property to send the data by calling the save function there

Comment: Yup. I tried that but the element input keeps open. It's weird. It's a way to close or reset thaht?